# Is it safe to schedule the same local notifications multiple times?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have this helper method to create a local notification that is meant to be called every day at a specific hour:

```
func create(_ type: NotificationType, time: Date, title: String, body: String, repeated: Bool = false) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    let triggerDate = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: time)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate, repeats: false)
    let identifier = type.rawValue
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    center.add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            fatalError("Unable to add request to Notification Center - \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

And then I call it every time the app is started:

```
notifications.create(.tomorrow, time: Date.tomorrowsTime,
                         title: "" ,
                         body: "",
                         repeated: true)
```

Is it safe if I schedule it every time the app is started ? Or I should make sure that is called just once, first time the app is run ?

Comment: If you are using the same identifier in you UNNotificationRequest I don't see any problem. **A unique identifier for the request (if identifier is not unique, a new notification request object is not created).**

Comment: You can also just cancel any pending request using the same identifier if you are concerned about it

Comment: Yep, it's always same identifier. Thanks.